Airflow script to schedule dag for every hour has loaded data for next 5 days instead of live updates every hour
[![Postgres][1]][1]
[![Airflow][2]][2]
I created an Airflow script that pulls info from Open weather api and loads into Postgres database locally.The Dag is running successfully and executes every hour however data for next 5 days has been loaded into my database instead of sequential loading of data every hour and updating the database. Whenever I trigger the Dag, the data is not updated anymore, just whatever data was loaded initially exists and no updates anymore.
Can someone help me in this ?
import requests
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import Error
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

# Define the DAG parameters
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 6, 28),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'metro_cities',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Fetch weather forecast data from OpenWeatherMap API and insert into PostgreSQL',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=1),  # Run every 1 hour
)

# Function to fetch weather forecast data from OpenWeather API
def fetch_weather_forecast(api_key, city):
    url = f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city}&appid={api_key}&units=metric'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f'Failed to fetch data: {response.status_code}')
        return None

# Function to insert forecast data into PostgreSQL
def insert_forecast_into_db(api_key, city, **kwargs):
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(
            user="postgres",
            password="password",
            host="localhost",
            port="5432",
            database="postgres"
        )
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        forecast_data = fetch_weather_forecast(api_key, city)
        if forecast_data:
            forecast_list = forecast_data.get('list', [])
            for forecast in forecast_list:
                date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(forecast['dt'])
                
                # Example: Inserting forecast data into a table
                cursor.execute("""
                    INSERT INTO weather_forecast (city, temperature, humidity, description, date_time)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
                    """, (
                        city,
                        forecast['main']['temp'],
                        forecast['main']['humidity'],
                        forecast['weather'][0]['description'],
                        date_time
                    ))

            connection.commit()
            print("Forecast data inserted successfully")
    except (Exception, Error) as error:
        print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
    finally:
        if connection:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")

# Define cities for forecast
cities = ['Seattle', 'Oakland', 'Atlanta']
api_key ='api'

# Define tasks in the DAG for each city
for city in cities:
    fetch_weather_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'fetch_weather_forecast_{city.lower().replace(" ", "_")}',
        python_callable=fetch_weather_forecast,
        op_args=[api_key, city],
        dag=dag,
    )

    insert_forecast_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'insert_forecast_into_postgres_{city.lower().replace(" ", "_")}',
        python_callable=insert_forecast_into_db,
        op_kwargs={'api_key': api_key, 'city': city},
        provide_context=True,  # This allows passing context (like XCom) to the function
        dag=dag,
    )

    # Define task dependencies
    fetch_weather_task >> insert_forecast_task ```


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/MzbFWpBW.png
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/261evCZM.png


Shouldn't you be using xcoms to get the data returned by the fetch_weather_task instead of this forecast_data = fetch_weather_forecast(
